# Circuit to exaggerate differences in current

Tags: audio, amplifier

Basically what I am after is some sort of a circuit which will amplify higher voltage signals, but possibly dampen lower voltage signals, in order to make a wider separation between high and low voltage. This is just for a little DIY project I am working on at home, and basically it would be comparable to setting your audio equipment to "Theater" mode vs. "Quiet" mode.
Would this be easily accomplished with a fairly simple circuit, or am I trying to go after something far too complex for a beginner?

What would be the name of a circuit similar to what I am attempting to build?

Comment: Yes, an expander. That seems to be exactly what I am looking for is a "Dynamic Range Expander" circuit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are describing is an [expander](http://www.mediacollege.com/audio/processing/expansion/). This performs the opposite function of a [compressor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_range_compression).

Basically, it is a amplifier (or simple attenuator, see below) circuit set up so that the gain is controlled by the incoming signal level. There are various ways of implementing this in a circuit, from simple to very complex. Here is an example of about the simplest compander (compressor/exander) circuit using a light dependent resistor and LED to control the attenuation:

[image: Basic Compander]

Here is the [page](http://www.schematicsforfree.com/archive/dir/Audio/Circuits/Dynamics+&+Gain+Control) of articles/schematics this came from which includes the explanation of the circuit and various other similar circuits. Google will turn loads more up.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're after some kind of expander circuit, which is half of a [compander](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companding). There are [many](http://electroschematics.com/265/audio-compander-schematic/) [example](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=701259) [circuits](http://hevirred.multiply.com/journal/item/17) [available](http://www.dicks-website.eu/limiter/enindex.html) online, with a great deal of them around the NE571 or NE572.

Comment: How about you add an example to your answer? We want to be the source of content not a place to find links. This helps down the road when people find this question from searching the web and might end up finding all of your links to be dead.